# Using numpy to create a list more efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an assignment to use numpy and to remove loops from the following code:

```
F = np.zeros(2*N)
for i in range(N):
  F[i] = v[N+i]

  if(i == 0) or (i == N-1):
    F[N+i] = 0
  else:
    F[N+i] = K*v[i+1]+v[i-1]-2*v[i]
```

My approach was along the lines of

```
np.append(v[-N:], [0], np.fromiter((K*v[i+1]+v[i-1]-2*v[i] for i in range(1,N-1))), [0])
```

However, this still contains a loop and feels too complex. Is there perhaps some code that would allow me to do this more efficiently / in a nicer way?

Thanks

Comment: Just slice your way through, e.g., `F[:N] = v[N:]` etc. No need for it to be a one-liner either.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer how would I use slices for the `K*v[i+1]+v[i-1]-2*v[i]` part of the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for-loop can be eliminated by vector calculation. Start indices are `i+1`, `i-1` or `i` for `i == 1` and end indices are the same for `i == N-1`:

```
F = np.concatenate([v[N:],[0], K*v[2:N]+v[0:N-2]-2*v[1:N-1], [0]])
```